# prove that there infinitely many $m$ such that $\frac{2^{m-1}-1}{8191m} \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory

Here is what i did :
$$2^{13}\equiv 1 [8191]$$
$$2^{26}\equiv 1 [8191]$$
since $m$ is odd 
so $$m-1=26k$$ with $$k\in \mathbb{N}$$
and we have $$2^{m-1}-1\equiv 0 [m]$$
Hence $m$ is prime 
soooo $$m=26k+1$$ with $m$ prime
I think that i should prove that there infinitely many primes $m$ such that$m\equiv 1[26]$

Comment: Actually, $2^{13}\equiv 1 [8191]$.

Comment: It doesn't follow from $2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ that $p$ is prime.  Try $p=341=11\cdot31.$  You are thinking of Fermat's little theorem, but this is the converse, which is not true in general.

Comment: You have a weird way of stating hypothesis as though they were conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What saulspatz said in the comments is true, $2^{m-1}\equiv 1\pmod m$ does not imply that $m$ is prime. However, it is true that $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, for any prime $p>2$, by Fermat's little theorem.

Thus, you are correct, since you only need to show that there are infinitely many such $m$, it is enough to show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $26k + 1$. This follows from [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).